# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript

Form for the selection this form look like selection and then select the code

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Multiple</label>
                      <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="select2">
                          <option>Alabama</option>
                          <option>Alaska</option>
                          <option>California</option>
                          <option>Delaware</option>
                          <option>Tennessee</option>
                          <option>Texas</option>
                          <option>Washington</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
```

This is the link Code error is here error comes on javaScript Function

```
         @section('footerSection')
              <script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/admin/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
             $( document ).ready(function() {

               $(".select2").select2();

              });
            </script>
             @endsection
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with $(".select2").select2(); ??

Comment: select2 is form selection element. Which is use for selction and also include javascript for suggestion for select.

Comment: please explain what the issue is. show the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the src order.  select2 is probably trying to use jquery before it is defined.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/admin/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: I do this as you said but now i am facing another problem design is not in right alignment

Comment: but this fixed your error right?  Maybe submit another question with the css code?